# cv2.pyd not generated when building opencv 3.1 from source on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've followed the methods shown over [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html#gsc.tab=0) and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html#gsc.tab=0) to install opencv from source. But despite following it step by step, cv2.pyd is not generated. The reason I'm building from source is because I need to apply a patch in matchers.cpp before building it, which I cannot do if I install from an executable.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem. And I dont know the reason why it is not being generated. But, the workaround is using the .whl (wheel) file to install the built libraries. So once you have built using Visual Studio, just download the corresponding wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and then,

- go to that location from cmd(Run as administrator)
- run **pip install (whl file)**
  Example  : pip install opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

Thats it. You should see the files in site-packages inside Python/Lib/.
What the whl file does is just move the files to the site packages. It somehow creates the cv2.pyd as well. If someone can explain in depth how that works it will be really helpful!

Hopefully, this works for you.

Comment: In effect what you have just said is "don't build from source, install a prebuilt copy using the whl file". In many situations it is required that you compile from source.